# How can I use a variable in React JS render method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning React JS.

Now, I am using a variable in App.js file and want to use this variable in render() method  in index.js file but it's showing me this error:

> ./src/index.js   Line 7:  'bioData' is not defined  no-undef
>
> Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

in App.js file I have this code:

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

function Person (props) {
  return (
    <div className="p1">
      <h1>{props.name}</h1>
      <h3>{props.skill}</h3>
    </div>
  );
}

var bioData = (
  <div>
    <Person name="alex" skill="designer" />
    <Person name="shibbir" skill="web developer" />
  </div>
);

export default Person;
```

and In index.js file I have following code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import Person from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(bioData, document.querySelector("root"));    
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

can you tell me why it's showing that erro?

Comment: Because you don't export that from App or import it in index?

Comment: Should I use this `export default bioData;` in App.js file?

Comment: Do you want it to be the default export? Why don't you try it? Note that it's not actually a component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you haven't imported `bioData` into `index.js` (or defined it locally). In modules, top-level declarations are not globals, modules have their own scope (thankfully). So `var bioData` in `App.js` doesn't define a global `index.js` sees.

If you want to use `biodata` in `index.js`, export it from `App.js`:

```
export var bioData = {/*...*/};
```

...and import it into `index.js`, perhaps on the line where you're importing `Person`:

```
import Person, { bioData } from './App';
```

Note that that's a *named* export/import. You asked in a comment whether you should use `export default bioData;` in `App.js`, but you can't, you already have a default export in `App.js` (`Person`). You can have only one default export (or none), and then as many named exports as you like (or none).

---

Side note: `var` is obsolete. Use `let` or `const`.

---

Side note 2, re this code:

```
ReactDOM.render(bioData, document.querySelector("root"));
```

Assuming you're trying to render to an `id="root"` element, it should be either `document.getElementById("root")` (more idiomatic) or `document.querySelector("#root")`, but not `document.querySelector("root")` (which looks for a `<root>...</root>` element).

Comment: Somehow It's showing me: `Target container is not a DOM element.`

Comment: @creativeartbd - That's a *different* problem than this question. Apparently, you don't have an `id="root"` element in your page.

Comment: in public folder, I have an index.html page where the root ID is already declared

Comment: @creativeartbd - Again, this is a different problem than the question. (Specifically, it's [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element).) That's the error you get when you pass `null` to ReactDOM as the second argument. So `getElementById` is returning `null`. See that question's answers for how to figure out why and fix it. My guess is that your `script` tags are in the wrong place (prior to the `id="root"` element).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I missed the hash sign (#).

Comment: @creativeartbd - Ah, you're using `querySelector`, not `getElementById`. Sorry, I missed that. Just FWIW, if you're looking up an element by ID, `getElementById("id")` is usually a better choice than `querySelector("#id")`. Happy coding!